# How to subtract hour of time from CSV

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I am trying to remove one hour off of the time in the last column of my data. I have tried using the lubridate package but it is just not working for me. Any solution would be helpful! TIA  [image: Here]

Comment: Just a good practice comment: your data may have started out as a CSV file or an Excel file or a table in a database or from any number of different sources. Once you've read it into R, it's a `data.frame` (in this case, more specifically a `tibble`). Don't call it a CSV anymore--it's not relevant where it came from.

Comment: Great, I appreciate the feedback. I'm new to R and to this site!

Comment: Please show the code you tried and tell exactly how it didn't work. Also in the future share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste that into R for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can perhaps be fixed at time of import, setting the time zone (see [readr's documentation](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_datetime.html)).

Once imported, you can subtract the correspondent time in seconds, like time -3600 (as there are 3600 seconds in a hour), and then you can convert it back using `lubridate` with something like:

```
data$Time <- lubridate::seconds_to_period(as.numeric(data$Time-3600))
```

To get back to the exact format you had before, after the previous step, you can reformat with something like:

```
library("lubridate")
data$Time <- lubridate::seconds_to_period(as.numeric(data$Time-3600)) 
data$Time <- sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hour(data$Time), minute(data$Time), second(data$Time))
```

Comment: Once I do this, it just displays the time in seconds and I need it in the H:M:S format. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: now I see, the Time column comes from readr::parse_time, https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_datetime.html - you can adjust the timezone when importing, or probably convert back, I'll adjust response